# How to grep the specific value from the output with shell script?

Tags: shell

I have a output like this

```
{
    "Tags": [
        {
            "ResourceType": "instance",
            "Value": "dev",
            "Key": "Group"
        },
        {
            "ResourceType": "instance",
            "Value": "web",
            "Key": "Name"
        }
    ]
}
```

With shell script, how can i get the "web" value? In other words, i only want to get the value if the "Key" equals "Name"

Comment: You didn't mention what shell you are using, but generally that'd be hard without parsing the JSON. Is it OK if your script depends on something like Node.js or PHP?

Comment: I use bash shell and it doesn't depend on any other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) for example:

```
command | jq ".Tags[1].Value"
```

Comment: Since i only want to get the py-sc without double quotation marks, is there any way to do this?